# NServiceBus distributor worker create a queue called PRIVATE$\order_queue$

Tags: msmq, nservicebus, worker, nservicebus-distributor

I have created an NServiceBus Distributor and Worker, running on separate machines.  When I run the worker, it successfully sends a message to the Distributor (and I can see it processed through the Storage queue) but for some reason an output queue is created on the Distributor called

'DIRECT=TCP:xx.xx.xx.xx\PRIVATE$\order_queue$ when the queue should be called 
'DIRECT=OS:WORKERDNSNAME\private$\myqueue'.

Does anyone know why the order_queue$ is being created?

Answer (score 2):

Shameless copy direct from an old post at [pg2e.blogspot.co.uk](http://pg2e.blogspot.co.uk/2008/04/transactional-queues-over-http-from.html):

> **Transactional queues over HTTP from private networks**
>
> When sending messages to a transactional queue over http/s from a
>   server without a public ip address the ACK-messages may have a hard
>   time reaching their destination. This is due to the same cause as in
>   [this](http://pg2e.blogspot.com/2008/03/sending-messages-using-msmq-over-http.html) post *(Basically NATting causing a mismatch with the message destination address)*.
>
> By default the receipts are sent to the sending computers name, which
>   of course will not work unless both parties resides on the same
>   network. To fix this you have to map the receipts to the public address
>   of the sender. This is done by creating an xml-file (of any name) in
>   *C:\WINDOWS\system32\msmq\mapping* with the following content.
>
> ```
> <StreamReceiptSetup xmlns="msmq-streamreceipt-mapping.xml"> 
>     <setup> 
>         <LogicalAddress>http://msmq.domain.com/*</LogicalAddress>
>         <StreamReceiptURL>http://[ADDRESS_TO_SENDER]/msmq/Private$/order_queue$</StreamReceiptURL>
>     </setup>
>     <default>http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx/msmq/Private$/order_queue$</default>
> </StreamReceiptSetup>
> ```
>
> Explanation: All messages sent to any queue at msmq.domain.com will
>   have their receipts sent to the given StreamReceiptURL. **The
>   order_queue$ queue is used to handle transactional control messages.**

I suspect later versions of MSMQ or NServiceBus handle creating this queue automatically without you having to create the XML file yourself.